# why is the pandas library giving constant Unicode error on different IDLEs?

Tags: python, pandas

i was coding on spyder3 IDLE when it suddenly stopped working and crashed, i was able to reset it, but as soon as i import Pandas to work with it, when i run it, it shows this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/INVENTARIT/exercise.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\INVENTARIT\pandas.py", line 10
    reading_file = open('C:\Users\INVENTARIT\Downloads\Death - Wikipedia.pdf'.decode('utf = 8')).read()
                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I left the Spyder3 IDLE and startes working in my Pycharm IDLE, importing pandas gives the exact error message.

Comment: Why are you `decoding` the file path?

Comment: Can you try running your script after removing `.decode('utf = 8')`?

Comment: And try to use forward slashes, Windows will deal fine with those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file called pandas.py in the same directory as your script. Which python is loading instead of the systems pandas library. You need to delete or rename it.

Comment: Oh! i deleted the other file with .pyc extension. it works perfectly now. thank you!